# perl: Exporter doesn't work with path elements in the `use` statement

Tags: perl, exporter

I have a perl problem: importing symbols, depending on the path elements in `@INC` and the `use` statement.

If I put the full path into `@INC`, the import works. If a part of the path is in the `use` statement the module to import is executed, but the import has to be done explicitly:

```
########################################
# @INC has: "D:/plu/lib/"

#------------------------------------------------
# Exporting file is here: "D:/plu/lib/impex/ex.pm"
#
use strict;
use warnings;
package ex;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw( fnQuark );

sub fnQuark { print "functional quark\n"; }

print "Executing module 'ex'\n";
1;

#------------------------------------------------
# Importing file, example 1, is here: "D:/plu/lib/impex/imp.pl"
#
use strict;
use warnings;
package imp;

use impex::ex;

ex->import( @ex::EXPORT );    # removing this line makes fnQuark unavailable!
                              # Why is this necessary, 'ex.pm' being an Exporter?
fnQuark();

#------------------------------------------------
#  Importing file, example 2, is here: "D:/plu/lib/impex/imp2.pl"
#
use strict;
use warnings;
package imp2;

use lib 'D:/plu/lib/impex';
use ex;

fnQuark();                    # works without explicit import
#-------------------------------------------------
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say

```
use Foo;
```

this is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { 
    require 'Foo.pm';
    Foo->import;
};
```

You've defined the package in your `ex.pm` to be named `ex`, so when you `use impex::ex`, Perl does an implicit `impex::ex->import`. But there is no package named `impex::ex`, so you have to manually do the import from `ex` to get your symbols.

The correct way to do this is to put your modules under an existing directory in `@INC` and name the package after the full path-name relative to the `@INC` directory. So your `impex/ex.pm` should begin with `package impex::ex;` and that's how you should `use` it.

If you're worried about package names being long and unwieldy, have a look at [aliased](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?aliased).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But I do not understand why I didn't have this problem before. I have so many modules, e. g. 'FotoArchive.pm' in lib/Foto, with the package name FotoArchive and Foto not in the @INC path. Why does that not cause the same problems when I invoke them via Foto::FotoArchive? -- Ah, I begin to see, because they don't export anything. So I got away with my mistake unnoticed for so long! Thank you!